# RESTful - URI definition of sales transaction

Tags: rest, uri

I´d develop some Restful services in my application, like (URI):

```
xxx/method/blah
yyy/method/bleh
zzz/method
```

all of these resources (xxx, yyy, zzz) are specifical products in my business and now i need design the sale definition to them. I think in:

```
xxx/sell
yyy/sell
zzz/sell
```

But it looks like to me not cohesive because i think that the sell behaviour should be an unique and specifical resource, like:

```
transaction/sell/xxx
transaction/sell/yyy
transaction/sell/zzz
```

What is (should be) right here for you?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be RESTful, you want the verb (eg. "sell") to be the HTTP method. The URI should identify the resource, not the action to be taken on the resource.

Comment: Hi janm. I agree with you, but my doubt is "should sell be part of a specifical resource, like "transaction/sell/xxx|yyy or zzz. ?"

Comment: I suspect that if it were a resource, it would be "sale" rather than "sell". A sale is a unique thing that could be a named resource. For example, applying the "sell" method to a product could produce a URI that pointed to the resultant sale resource.

Comment: If the resource is a specific transaction, then that makes sense. If the resource is a product, then it doesn't make sense, at least in RESTful terms. Creating a sale could be applying a "sell" method to a product URI, which then returns a URI to the transaction, which could be (for example only): "/transaction/sale/prod-id/transaction-id", with appropriate values for the "-id" part.

Comment: To say "part of a specific resource" doesn't make sense. Each complete URI is a distinct resource. The order and structure of the URI components is an implementation detail of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to decide between functional oriented design (where the function, sell, is in the center, and it perform actions on different entities, the products) and object oriented design (where the object, the product, is in the center, and each object has method, such as sell).

There is no "right" and "wrong" answer here - it really depends on you language paradigm. So, I think you should confirm with the language you are implementing the service: If it is an OO (Object Oriented) language (and most chances you are using an OO language), you should use the OO approach. 

In Java+RESTEasy (for instance) the implementation approach is quite obvious:

```
@Path("product")
public class Product {
    // Product fields
    // ...

    @Path("sell")
    @GET
    public void sell(){
        // Selling implementation
        // ...
    }
}
```

The RESTEasy framework will translate the request of http://.../product/sell into invocation of sell() on an instance of product object.